# Angular Route & pagination in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-routing

I'm doing a pagination in angular-ui-bootstrap

```
searchapp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider
    .when('/search?page', {
      controller: 'classifiedAdController',
      reloadOnSearch: false
  });
});

searchapp.controller('classifiedAdController', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, ClassifiedAd) {
$scope.$watch('currentPage', function(page) {
      console.log(page);
      $location.search('page', page);
    });
});
```

here is my implementation, everything work fine when the page and pagination is load properly localhost:3000/search. Then when I click page 1,2,3, the url will change to localhost:3000/search?page=2

But when I manually copy localhost:3000/search?page=2 in the addressbar, it will route my url back to localhost:3000/search

any hints or idea to implement this? And how actually angularRoute provider do?

Answer (score 1):

I would have use a more Angular way to do so, your route could be /search/page/2, you can add parameters to your angular route using :parameters, it look like:

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/search/page/:page', {
       controller: 'classifiedAdController',
       reloadOnSearch: false
   });
```

Then you will have a "page" parameters you can retrieve from your controller.
It might work as well to have something like: `.when('/search?page=:page', {` but I never tried

Comment: yupz, i found /search?page is the correct syntax, but no idea why, when I manually keyin localhost:3000/search?page=2 it will route me back to localhost:3000/search. This actually is not the behaviour i wish to.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `?page` in route

Use this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/search', {
        controller: 'classifiedAdController',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    });
```

Then in your controller:

```
  $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $location.search().page
  }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
      $scope.page = newVal;
  });
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/m6e5lOClSiUODRc3aloL?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm, but I wish to manually do localhost:3000/search?page=2, then it will actually query the database for page2 result. your solution I tried, wont work...any idea?

Comment: You could add a watcher on the `$location.search().page;` Check out the answer I've edited now.

Comment: hi @Raghav, what is the different between your implementation and my existing implementation? I see no different, and when I changed your code to test it out, yah, it remain the url, but my angular bootstrap pagination is not working anymore. Thought?

Comment: You are watching on a scope variable and when changed, you're changing the location parameter. In my implementation, I am watching for changes in location parameter and then updating the scope variable.

Comment: hmm,but my pagination is not working anymore when I click next page or previous page, the parameter dont change..